# X11 Forwarding for user without home directory

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I have a privileged user without home folder with ssh access. I try to do X forwarding but I get the message */usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority*
If I don't have home folder logically .Xauthority doesn't exist.
Is there a way to replace the location or tell xauth to use a different file?

Comment: If the user is privileged, use it to *create* the home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the location of this file by setting the XAUTHORITY environment variable.

```
$ export XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.Xauthority_$USER
```